# How to change the colormap of a pie chart?

Tags: python, pandas

Simple question here, I am creating a pie chart in pandas for the value counts of a dataset's regional spread:

```
df['region'].value_counts().plot.pie
```

I want to use the colormap "cool" to color this so it matches my other visualizations, is this possible or am I oversimplifying? Do I need to assign a color to each region or can I somehow just add a colormap='cool' somewhere in here? New to visualizations here...

Answer (score 3):

When not plotting straight from pandas, `pie` uses the `colors` argument, which takes a list of color codes.

You can retrieve color codes from some matplotlib colormaps using `plt.cm.desired_colormap_name.colors`

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.pie(s, colors=plt.cm.Pastel2.colors)
plt.show()
```

[image: pie chart example]

Colormap names here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the argument `cmap='cool'` to the `.pie` method. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
s.plot.pie(cmap='cool')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: pie() does not have a 'cmap' argument, it uses 'colors'

Comment: @Tilman this code runs for me and I'm using the latest version of both `matplotlib` and `pandas`. the documentation can be viewed [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html)

Comment: Sorry I had no idea matplotlib integrates with pandas like this. I am just using matplotlib and matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie doesn't have the cmap argument. (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie)

Comment: no worries – i've always thought of the pandas `DataFrame.plot` as a convenience method for developers who don't use `matplotlib` all that much – but this also comes with its share of arguments that might not seem consistent to people who primarily use matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

use as the "cmap" additional parameter in pie

```
df['region'].value_counts().plot.pie(cmap=plt.get_cmap('cool'))
```